# jQuery JavaScript - can't invoke the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function which suppose to count number of characters in post, and append new posts to the list. 
**markup:**

```
<div class="new-comment">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <textarea rows="3" placeholder="What's on your mind?" class="form-control status-box"></textarea>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div class="button-group pull-right">
    <p class="counter">140</p><a ng-click="post = post + 1" ng-init="post=0" class="btn btn-primary">Post</a>
  </div>
  <ul class="posts"></ul>
</div>
```

and js:

```
var posts = function() {
  $('.btn').click(function() {
    var post = $('.status-box').val();
    $('<li>').text(post).prependTo('.posts');
    $('.status-box').val('');
    $('.counter').text('140');
    $('.btn').addClass('disabled'); 
  });

  $('.status-box').keyup(function() {
    var postLength = $(this).val().length;
    var charactersLeft = 140 - postLength;
    $('.counter').text(charactersLeft);

    if(charactersLeft < 0) {
      $('.btn').addClass('disabled'); 
    }
    else if(charactersLeft == 140) {
      $('.btn').addClass('disabled');
    }
    else {
      $('.btn').removeClass('disabled');
    }
  });

  $('.btn').addClass('disabled');
}

$(window).load(posts);
```

Now this version DOESN'T work. Same with `$(document).ready(posts);` The whole function just sits there, no errors in the console, nothing. 
 
 And thats where I'm getting confused, because if I'll put it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var posts = function() {
      $('.btn').click(function() {
        var post = $('.status-box').val();
        $('<li>').text(post).prependTo('.posts');
        $('.status-box').val('');
        $('.counter').text('140');
        $('.btn').addClass('disabled'); 
      });

      $('.status-box').keyup(function() {
        var postLength = $(this).val().length;
        var charactersLeft = 140 - postLength;
        $('.counter').text(charactersLeft);

        if(charactersLeft < 0) {
          $('.btn').addClass('disabled'); 
        }
        else if(charactersLeft == 140) {
          $('.btn').addClass('disabled');
        }
        else {
          $('.btn').removeClass('disabled');
        }
      });

      $('.btn').addClass('disabled');
    }

  $(window).scroll(function() {
      posts();
  });

  posts();

});
```

..it Works! But then it gets dependent on the **scroll**. I can't have that dependency. And NOTHING else works. Like if I try to invoke it by:

```
  $(window).load(function() {
      posts();
  });
```

...still nothing.

Comment: Just a thought. If I paste 141 signs into your text field you button isn't disabled. You should use `charactersLeft >= 140` for your status box check.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/b0vyxpn4/ works as expected i think